# How to fix «We couldn’t connect to your chat session» for Apple support chat?

Tags: websites

I am authenticated.
I tried Chrome on Windows and iPhone: the error is the same.

[image]

Comment: Try Safari? (Or Vivaldi, Firefox.) You'll at least have a private conversation. ;-)